# Issue with fixed width tcolorbox in start of new par (right to left context)

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, right-to-left, bidi

I have this example of a fixed width `tcolorbox` in RTL context inserted in the beginning of a paragraph, if I add `\indent` indentation appears normally  but without it box go in opposite direction! Is there any way to solve this problem?

I look for commands to add before `tcolorbox` which give correct result in all cases

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\pagedir TRT \pardir TRT \bodydir TRT \textdir TRT

%% without \leavevmode 

% this is fine
\indent 
{\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}[width=3cm,nobeforeafter] 
box
\end{tcolorbox}}text

% not fine
{\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}[width=3cm,nobeforeafter]
 box
\end{tcolorbox}}text

%% with \leavevmode

% fine
{\leavevmode\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}[width=3cm,nobeforeafter]
 box
\end{tcolorbox}}text

% not fine
{\leavevmode\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}
 box
\end{tcolorbox}}

\end{document}
```

[image]