tcolorbox gets cut off when using Hebrew with babel
I am trying to create a nice boxed paragraph with the tcolorbox package, but it doesn't work with my Hebrew document which uses babel. This sample code, for example, works fine in English without babel:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Hello
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


However, if I modify the code to use babel with a Hebrew font, the box gets cut off and it's not anywhere near the text:
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Assistant}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
שלום
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614238/issue-with-fixed-width-tcolorbox-in-start-of-new-par-right-to-left-context

use layout=tabular graphics as key

I found that adding layout=tabular graphics to babel fixes the issue. Thanks to Ulrike Fischer who suggested it in the comments.
